# Terminate the complete child process tree in linux when parent dies

Tags: c++, linux, process, fork

I have a cpp process which forks and create another child process. This child process can spin up other child processes. I want to terminate the complete child process tree when the **parent dies or crashes**. Is there a way to achieve this by using prctl or something else?
I thought of using `prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL)` but it seems like it is only able to kill the immediate child and not the complete process tree.

One more point - I am resetting the child's pgrp to its own PID when I fork using `setpgid(0, 0)`. This is done so that parent can kill the process tree using `kill(-pid, SIGKILL)`. But **crashing parent case** is missing in my arsenal.

Comment: you need to search and find all descendants of your child and `SIGTERM` all of them.

Comment: @AhmedAEK i guess you are talking about creating a new reaper process to do so?

Comment: Killing with parent process id kills all subtree like $ kill -- -12087

Comment: @ÖöTiib parent crashes or exits?

Comment: That command line kills 12087 and all its subprocesses.

Comment: If the parent of a process dies, the [children will be adopted by init](https://linuxjourney.com/lesson/process-termination#). You would need to spawn a reaper

Comment: @SimonC is there a pre-existing tool which can act as a reaper? Or some guide which can help me writing a good and robust reaper?

Comment: Have the parent process do nothing but fork off the real parent process, `wait` for it, and when it terminates, for any reason, then `kill(-pid, SIGKILL)`.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been tagged with "linux", so I will give a Linux-specific answer.

One possible technique is for the parent to trace the child using `ptrace` and specify the flag `PTRACE_O_EXITKILL` using `PTRACE_SETOPTIONS`. This flag tells the kernel to kill the tracee if the tracer terminates for any reason. In order to ensure that any descendants of the tracee will also be killed, I think you also have to specify `PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE`, `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC`, `PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK`, and `PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK`, so that any child processes will automatically also become traced by the same tracer. However, I assume that `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC` will  be ignored when a process `exec`s a setuid or setgid executable or acquires any capabilities from an `exec` call, so this technique would not totally guarantee that no descendant process can "escape".

It seems that a more robust solution is possible using *PID namespaces*; see an introduction to this feature [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/531419/) and documentation [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pid_namespaces.7.html). In short, if you create a new child process using `CLONE_NEWPID`, that child process becomes the initial process of a brand new PID namespace. Any processes created by that initial process then belong to the new namespace, and when the initial process terminates (for any reason), the kernel kills all other processes in the namespace.

Note that the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability is required in order to employ the `CLONE_NEWPID` flag. That means you might need to create a dedicated binary with the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` filesystem capability bit set, whose only purpose is to create the initial process of the new PID namespace, and then exit; the child process, meanwhile, should immediately drop this capability if it is no longer needed.

Comment: About the ptrace solution- does it impact the performance of the processes ( child or parent )?

Comment: @tanmay001 Yes - a process that is being traced will stop every time it receives a signal, and every time one of the subscribed events occurs; for example, if you have `PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK`, then when the tracee forks, both the tracee and the tracee's child will stop, and the tracee's child will automatically become a tracee. The tracer must use a `wait` system call to detect the tracee's stop, and then use `PTRACE_CONT` to restart a stopped tracee.